# Py4JJavaError while calling .fit() in pyspark RandomForestClassifier

Tags: python, java, pyspark, random-forest, py4j

Im trying to run a RandomForestClassifier model on my dataset and below error pops up.Anyone knows a solution? Im using Spark version 3.3.1 and Python version 3.8.

```
    model_df = output.select(["features","OrderMonth"])
    train_df, test_df = model_df.randomSplit([0.7,0.3])

    from pyspark.ml.classification import RandomForestClassifier

    rfc = RandomForestClassifier(numTrees=10, labelCol="OrderMonth").fit(train_df)
                           
    rf_pred = rfc.transform(test_df)
    rf_pred.show()
```

Py4JJavaError Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-56-5ed675f09e07> in <module>
7 from pyspark.ml.classification import RandomForestClassifier
8
----> 9 rfc = RandomForestClassifier(numTrees=10, labelCol="OrderMonth").fit(train_df)#change n_e to a bigger number
10
11 #rfc.fit(X_train,y_train)

Comment: is this  java related question  . why is java tagged

Comment: The code is in python. But it use apache spark with JVM. @GiovanniContreras